# How to check UID exists using ldapsearch

Tags: shell, ldap

I would like to have a shell script use 'ldapsearch' to compare UIDs listed in a text file with those on a remote LDAP directory.

I'm no shell script expert, and would appreciate any assistance. The following loops through a text file given as an argument, but what I need is to echo when a UID in my text file does not exist in the LDAP.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `cat $1`;
  do ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-66.example.com -b ou=People,dc=crm,dc=example,dc=com uid=$i | grep uid: | awk '{print $2}';
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

url="ldaps://ldap-66.example.com"
basedn="ou=People,dc=crm,dc=example,dc=com"

for i in `cat $1`; do
    if ldapsearch -x -H "$url" -b "$basedn" uid=$i uid > /dev/null
    then
        # Do nothing
        true
    else
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: Anttix, that worked with the addition of the 'grep' and 'awk' at the end of the out= line. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! However I updated the script to be more shellish (using exit value) so you probably want to try that out as well.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it! I really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no need to use `cat $1`, which will break as soon as your file contains blanks; use `while read -r i; do … done <"$1"` instead.
You also should quote "uid=$1" to prevent it to break on blanks.
You can safe the `then true else` part by doing `if ! ldapsearch …; then echo "$1"; done` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Anttix, this is the final version that worked. Thanks again. Does this mark the question as accepted?

```
#!/bin/sh

url="ldaps://ldap-66.example.com"
basedn="ou=People,dc=crm,dc=example,dc=com"

for i in `cat $1`; do
    if ldapsearch -x -H "$url" -b "$basedn" uid=$i | grep uid: | awk '{print $2}' > /dev/null
    then
        # Do nothing
        true
    else
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can combine `grep` and `awk` to `awk '/uid:/ {print $2}/`. Also my other comments from above apply regarding the use of quoting and use of `cat $i`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

uids="${1:?missing expected file argument}"
URL='ldaps://ldap-66.example.com'
BASE='ou=People,dc=crm,dc=example,dc=com'

ldapsearch \
  -x -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -c \
  -H "$URL" \
  -b "$BASE" \
  -f "$uids" \
  '(uid=%s)' uid |
sed \
  -r -n \
  -e 's/^uid: //p' \
  -e 's/^uid:: (.+)/echo "\1"|base64 -d/ep' |
grep \
  -F -x -v \
  -f - \
  "$uids"
```

## Explanation

### for the `ldapsearch` part

- You can invoke `ldapsearch -f` just once to perform **multiple** searches and read them from a file `$uids`.
- The `(uid=%s)` is used as a template for each line, where the `%s` is filled in for each line.
- The `-c` is needed to continue even on errors, e.g. when a UID is **not** found.
- The `-x` enforces *simple authentication* with should be considered insecure. Better use SASL.
- The `-LLL` will remove un-needed cruft from the `ldapsearch` output.
- The `-o ldif-wrap=no` will prevent lines longer than 79 characters from being wrapped - otherwise `grep` may only pick up the first part of your user names.
- The `uid` tells `ldapsearch` to only return that attribute and skip all the other attributes we're not interested in; saves some network bandwidth and processing time.

### for the `sed` part

- The `-r` enabled *extended regular expressions* turning `+`, `(…)` into operators; otherwise they have to be pre-fixed with a back-slash `\`.
- The `-n` tells `sed` to do not print each line by default but only when told to do so using an explicit print command `p`.
- The `s/uid: //` will strip that prefix from lines containing it.
- The `s/uid:: …/…/ep` part is needed for handling non-ASCII-characters like Umlauts as `ldapsearch` encodes them using `base64`.
- The suffix `…p` will print only those lines which were substituted.

### for the `grep` part

- The `-F` tells `grep` to not use *regular expression pattern matching*, but *plain text*; this becomes important if your names contain `.`, `*`, parenthesis, ….
- The `-x` enforces *whole line matching* so searching for `foo` will not also match `foobar`.
- The `-f -` tells `grep` to read the patterns from STDIN, that is the *existing* UIDs found by `ldapsearch`.
- The `-v` inverts the search and will **filter out** those *existing users*.
- The `$uids` will again read the list of *all requested users*. After removing the *existing users* the list of *missing users* will remain.

## Issues with previous solutions

The previous solutions all had certain kinds of issues:

- missing `grep`
- missing quoting which breaks as soon as blanks are involved
- use-less use of `cat`
- use-less use of `grep` when `awk` is also used
- inefficient because for each UID many processes get `fork()`ed
- inefficient because for each UID a separate search is performed
- did not work for long user names
- did not work for user names containing regular expression meta characters
- did not work for user names containing Umlauts