# What's the best way to write an LDAP client in Python

Tags: python, ldap, openldap, python-ldap

First of all I have to say that I don't know LDAP so in this question I'll try to explain what are my thoughts about the task that I have to perform.

I need to develop an application, **essentially a LDAP client**, for authentication on an LDAP Server.
My first problem is to try authentication on the LDAP server available in the company where I work.

### Use ldapsearch to test authentication

I know the program `ldapsearch`. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571558/how-was-authentication-built-on-ldap) explains that is it possible to use it for LDAP authentication.
So `ldapsearch` can be used to test the authentication on an LDAP server

One way to use of `ldapsearch` by command line is:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.example.com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Previous command uses the following options:

- `-H ldapURI`: Specify URI referring to the LDAP server
- `-D bindDN`: Use the Distinguished Name `bindDN` to bind to the LDAP directory
- `-W`: Prompt for simple authentication
- `-b searchbase`: Use searchbase as the starting point for the search instead of the default.

The command execution queries the LDAP server `ldap.example.com` and asks the insertion of the password for the user with Common Name *admin* (`cn=admin`). If the password of *admin* is not correct the result is the error message:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

If the inserted password is correct the output contains the following `0 Success` message:

```
...
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
...
```

### Integrate ldapsearch inside an application?

By `ldapsearch` I have tested with success the LDAP authentication on my company LDAP Server. Now I have a question: is `ldapsearch` suited for direct used inside a LDAP client? And in this case:

- Is it correct to use the different `ldapsearch` output (described above) to know if a user has inserted the correct password?
- The LDAP client have to call the external program `ldapsearch`?

### How to write a client to direct authenticate on a LDAP server?

For example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752516/how-to-check-uid-exists-using-ldapsearch) `ldapsearch` is used in a `shell script` to verified which users of a list are present on a LDAP Server but I suspect that it isn't suited for direct use inside a program write in Python or C.

If I exclude the use of `ldapsearch` I have to direct implement the LDAP authentication in a Client application (may be in Python language).

Without `ldapsearch` how can I implement the protocol LDAP in Python or in other language?

Thank you

Comment: You should not be running `ldapsearch` to perform authentication. Most languages (Python, PHP, Go, C, etc) have support for LDAP; you should be interacting with LDAP via the API bindings

Comment: @larsks Maybe I have to write the application in Python (or in C). Please could you give me some tips about the support at least in Python.

Comment: I've found `python-ldap` that provides an API to access LDAP Server. I'll try to use it immediately.

Comment: That's probably a good place to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the question I think that the direct use of `ldapsearch` for authentication on LDAP server **is not a good idea**, in fact, after read carefully [the link indicated in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571558/how-was-authentication-built-on-ldap) I have understood that the author has cited the use of `ldapsearch` only as an experiment, and this is clear when he says:

> That may be summarized as (as experiment in command line):
>
> ```
> $ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.company.com -s sub -b 'dc=europe,dc=com' "uid=XYZ"
> ```

It is better use API provided by various programming languages. In particular I've decided to write a Python application.
I suppose that `ldapsearch` can be use for authentication in a `bash` script.

### Python application for authentication on LDAP Server

To authenticate on a LDAP Server by a Python application is possible to use the `python-ldap` module; this is a wrapper of OpenLDAP library and provides a Python API to interact with a LDAP Server.

Useful link:

- The documentation of `python-ldap` can be found [here](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.3/).
- An useful example code which uses `python-ldap` can be found at [this link](https://gist.github.com/DiegoQueiroz/d35d8c8f52b58df2f39b4eed0c2c9520).

The [example program](https://gist.github.com/DiegoQueiroz/d35d8c8f52b58df2f39b4eed0c2c9520) allows the authentication on a LDAP Server by insertion of the credentials of an existent account (domain,username,password) and after the authentication, it executes a query on LDAP database (as `ldapsearch`).
The code defines the function `query_activedirectory()` which can be used to query the LDAP Server.
To  call the function is used the code below:

```
# the function returns a generator, so it won't fetch anything yet
response = query_activedirectory(
  uri="ldap://yourserver.domain.local:389",
  bindDN="cn=yourname,OU=folder,OU=folder,DC=domain,DC=local",
  bindPW="your_password",
  baseDN="OU=folder,OU=folder,DC=domain,DC=local",
  filterstr="&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=cool_group,OU=folder,OU=folder,DC=domain,DC=local)",
  attrlist=["userPrincipalName", "givenName"],  # None to fetch all attributes
  timeout=-1,    # wait indefinitely
  pagesize=1000
)
```

To execute the example code with the Server LDAP present in my company I have adapted the content of the following variable to be compliant to my company settings:

- `uri` --> in the example its value is `"ldap://yourserver.domain.local:389"` while for example in my company the TCP port is `3268` and obviously the rest of URI is different
- `bindDN` (stands for *bind Distinguish Name*) --> in the example its value is `"cn=yourname,OU=folder,OU=folder,DC=domain,DC=local"`
- `bindPW` (stands for *bind Password*) --> in the example its value is `"your_password"`
- `baseDN` (stands for *base Distinguish Name*) --> in the example its value is `"OU=folder,OU=folder,DC=domain,DC=local"`
- `filterstr` (correspond to the `searchbase` passed to `-b` argument of `ldapsearch`) --> check the example code for the value of filter
- `attrlist` --> in the example its value is `["userPrincipalName", "givenName"]`

This is the best way that I have found for authentication on a LDAP server by a python application.
I have followed the hint of @larsks (see above comments).